# Как конвертировать SQL таблицу в CSV?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv, jupyter-notebook

перейду к сути, у меня есть таблица: t.sql , я бы хотел её конвертировать в t.csv, чтобы загрузить в python, как это лучше сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710263/how-do-i-create-a-csv-file-from-database-in-python

Comment: В принципе, вы можете пропустить этап файла csv и загружать данные в Pandas сразу из sql базы.

Comment: суть в том, что мне нужно написать цикл на питоне, а не через sql.